# Chrome Extension: Can it be done: Request to local rest service

Tags: javascript, rest, google-chrome, ip

I have a need for a solution to a repetitive task I do in Google Chrome.

I come across IP addresses once in a while, and I need to geo locate them.

On my system I already have a REST service that If I called a certain url:

```
http://localhost:8080/json/8.8.8.8
```

I get a JSON response with GEO data.

I want to create a chrome extension that would trigger a geo rest call on selection or even hovering over a IPv4 string.

Is such an extension possible? Would it be blocked by cross domain request protection?

Answer (score 0):

You can run the following scriptlet directly from Chrome's address bar:

```
javascript:var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest;xhr.open('GET', 'http://localhost:8080/json/'+window.getSelection().toString(), true);xhr.onload = function (e) {alert(xhr.responseText)};xhr.send();
```

(note that you'll need to prepend the "javascript:" to the text on the address bar when copying from here because Chrome trims it when pasting).

Add this as a new page bookmark (name it something like "IP Geo Data") and put it on the bookmarks bar. Alternatively just type its name and choose it on from the ombibox autocomplete. You'll need to have the IP you want data about selected.

You're right about the cross domain protection, but since you control the service on your localhost:8080/json, just have it add the following headers on requests made to that path:

```
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true

Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization,Content-Type,Accept,Origin,User-Agent,DNT,Cache-Control,X-Mx-ReqToken,Keep-Alive,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do is as an extension to chrome, content scripts, message passing and setting up proper permissions.

[Content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts) will run on selected (or all) pages and can do whatever you want with the page. They just sandboxed from page's JavaScript environment. You can develop a hover action which recognize IP address and [send the information](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) to the [background page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) where it can be processed (in environment and especially permissions of the extensions which are not available in context of content scripts).

In the background page you can make a request using either [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Request) function. After you process the data you can return the result to the page via message passing or do whatever you want with it.

In the [manifest file](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest) you can set up specific URL you want to send information to or `<all_urls>` to have permission to send request everywhere.

```
...
"permissions": [
  "http://*.google.com/"
],
...
```

Then your request won't be subject of CORS and same domain policy.